# AttributeError: window object has no attribute tk

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have a tinker program with multiple windows.

Code :

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *


class window(Toplevel):
  def __init__(self, master=None):
        self.master=master
        self.title("Add Customer Record")
        window= tk.Tk()
        window.geometry("500x400")


class MainWindow:
  def __init__(self, master=None):
    self.master = master
    self.title("Shopping Mall Management")
    self.master.geometry("500x300")
    Button(self.master, text="Add customer record", command=self.open_save_record_window).pack(pady=20)


root = window()
main_window = MainWindow(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Error :

```
AttributeError : window has no attribute tk.
```

I'm unable to resolve this error. Any help would be helpful to me.

Comment: Yes, You just need to add `root=tk.TK()` and `super()` in both methods

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to resolve adding super()

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

roottk=tk.Tk()

class window(Toplevel):
  def __init__(self, master=None):
        super(window, self).__init__()
#        window= tk.Tk()
        self.master=master
        self.title("Add Customer Record")


class MainWindow(window):
  def __init__(self, master=None):
    super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
    self.master = master
    self.title("Shopping Mall Management")
    self.master.geometry("500x300")
    Button(self.master, text="Add customer record", command=open_save_record_window).pack(pady=20)


def open_save_record_window(self):
        window(self.master)


root = window()
main_window = MainWindow(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You create three windows when the program starts: instance of `Tk()`, instance of `window()` and instance of `MainWindow()`.  I don't think it is what you want.  I think what you want is only an instance of `MainWindow()` when program starts, and create an instance of `window()` when the button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Re-wrote your first script.

- In line 8, add `tk.Toplevel()`
- in line 9, change `selt.title` to `self.master.title(....`
- In line 16, add `self.master = tk.Tk()` in `MainWindow` class.
- In line 17, change `selt.title` to `self.master.title(....`
- In line 19, add prefix `Button` widget `tk.Button`
- In line 22, create `open_save_record_window` function. Do whatever
  you want.

Snippet re-wrote:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *


class window(Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        self.master = master
        self.master = tk.Toplevel()
        self.master.title("Add Customer Record")         
        self.master.geometry("500x400")


class MainWindow:
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        self.master = master
        self.master = tk.Tk()
        self.master.title("Shopping Mall Management")         
        self.master.geometry("500x300")
        tk.Button(self.master, text="Add customer record", command=self.open_save_record_window).pack(pady=20)
    
    def open_save_record_window(self):
        self.master.destroy()
       
if __name__=='__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.withdraw()
    app = window(root)
    main_window = MainWindow(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have used inheritance wrong. I would suggest

- `MainWindow` inherits from `tk.Tk`
- `window` (better use `Window`) inherits from `tk.Toplevel`
- create instance of `MainWindow` only when program starts
- create instance of `window` (use `Window` instead as suggested above) when the button is clicked

```py
import tkinter as tk

class Window(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.title("Add Customer Record")
        self.geometry("500x400")

class MainWindow(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title("Shopping Mall Management")
        self.geometry("500x300")
        tk.Button(self, text="Add customer record", command=self.open_save_record_window).pack(pady=20)

    def open_save_record_window(self):
        win = Window(self)
        # do other stuff ...

root = MainWindow()
root.mainloop()
```